# 2.3.0 - Custom Payment Method - Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, magento2.3, payment-gateway, magento2.3.0

I have a **custom payment method** that uses the `cc-form` to take **debit/credit card payments**.

After the **user** has entered their **card details**, they are **re-directed** to my **controller** with a **hidden form**, then to the **3dsecure page**.

After 3dsecure, they are **re-directed** to the same controller and **various logic is checked**.

After the logic is valid, they are re-directed to the **checkout success page**.

This was working with **Magento 2.2**, but in **2.3.0** this is not working.

After placing order, I am re-directed to **3dsecure** as normal, but on returning from 3dsecure, I am re-directed to the home page with

> "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page."

Comment: I have the same issue.. Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your Response Controller must implement CsrfAwareActionInterface and 2 of its methods. Your response controller should be like this.Then only form key issues will fix. I have the same issue in paytabs payment method and resolved using this way

```
    use Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

    class CustomPaymentResponse extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements CsrfAwareActionInterface
    {

        /** 
         * @inheritDoc
         */
        public function createCsrfValidationException(
            RequestInterface $request 
        ): ?InvalidRequestException {
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * @inheritDoc
         */
        public function validateForCsrf(RequestInterface $request): ?bool
        {
            return true;
        }
       /**
         * Dispatch request
         *
         * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
         * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
         */
       public function execute()
        {
        //your response check
        }
    }
```